# Set background image compatible for all iDevices

Tags: xcode, user-interface, swift, xcode6

When creating background image for xCode project in Swift, and I also want it to be compatible for all iPhone and iPad devices, do I have to create it like i created the app icon? With all the @2x names, or do i only need 1 image?

And what size should the image be?

Answer (score 1):

> **What size should the image be?**

The size of your images depends on how large they are on screen. For example, say you have a `UIImageView` that has as width and height of 100 **points**:

- On an iPad 2 (which doesn't have a retina display) you would be
  using a *1x* image and so your image file would be 100x100 **pixels**.
- On an iPhone 5 (which uses a *2x* retina display) your image file would need to be 200x200 **pixels**.
- On an iPhone 6+ (which uses a *3x* display) your image file would need to be 300x300 **pixels**.

> **When creating background image for xCode project in Swift, and I also want it to be compatible for all iPhone and iPad devices, do I have to create it like i created the app icon? With all the @2x names, or do i only need 1 image?**

You should have a look at Image Sets in Asset Catalogs.

From Apple:

> Image sets: Used for most types of images, an image set contains all the versions, or representations, of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors.

Here's some more information on them: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

To create one:

**1.** Create a new file. Then go to *Resource* and select *Asset Catalog*.

[image]

**2.** Press **Next** and give your catalog a name.

**3.** To add an *Image Set*, select your *Asset Catalog* (the `.xcassets` file). Then press the plus button in the bottom left hand corner and select *New Image Set*.

[image]

**4.** You can rename the the *Image Set* if you want, by default its name is 'Image'. This is the name you use to reference your image in code or IB.

**5.** Now you've got your image set you can drag and drop images into *1x*, *2x* or *3x*. Or you can change the *Devices* (in the Attributes Editor) to *Device Specific* and select specific screen sizes for your images.

[image]

**6.** Now in your code you can create a `UIImage` using the following:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Image") 
// Just replace "Image" with the name of your image set.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since XCode 6 it's possible to use vector based graphics. This gives you the opportunity to create one vector graphic and during compilation XCode creates the necessary PNGs for iOS (actually iOS 8 does not have full support for vector based graphics).

I use Sketch 3 for creating and working with assets, so there you can create an icon (or whatever) and export it as pdf (Note you have to choose 0.5x, because this is handled in XCode as the smallest icon).

For the sizes of app icons check [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html), else you just use the size your imageView is

Answer (score 0):

You have to create them in different resolutions. 
For more details you can have a look:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2

You can find the right resolutions at the point: "Launch file or image"